# apache-poi excel generation: different image size on multiple sheets

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm working on piece of code that generates Excel (*.xlsx) workbook with 2 sheets. On both I'm going to place in the top left corner the same [logo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn7cF.png) picture (151x90px). First sheet differs only from the second in first column width. It's wider on first sheet.

After excel file generation the picture on the first sheet looks fine however on the second sheet it's wider (110%)

How can I make pictures have it's original size on both sheets?

I'm using apache-poi 3.17

Here is my example code:

```
package mchodun.excel;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Drawing;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Picture;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ExcelFileTest {

    @Test
    public void testImage() throws IOException {
        Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
                "/Users/mchodun/Desktop/logo.png");
        byte[] pictureBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        createSheet(workbook, pictureBytes, true);
        createSheet(workbook, pictureBytes, false);

        final File fileDest = Paths.get("/Users/mchodun/Desktop", "test.xlsx")
                .toFile();
        // gets output stream
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileDest);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    private void createSheet(Workbook workbook, byte[] pictureBytes,
                             boolean changeColumnWidth) {
        final int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(pictureBytes,
                Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        if (changeColumnWidth) {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 16000);
        }
        final CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        final Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        final ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

        // create an anchor with upper left cell and bottom right cell
        anchor.setCol1(0);
        anchor.setRow1(0);
        anchor.setCol2(0);
        anchor.setRow2(0);

        Picture picture = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
        Row row0 = sheet.createRow(0);
        row0.setHeight((short) (picture.getImageDimension().getHeight() * 15));

        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell10 = row1.createCell(0);
        cell10.setCellValue("Value");

        picture.resize();
    }
```

}

Comment: For me this is not reproducible. Exactly your code produces a workbook `test.xlsx` having the `logo.png` shape in both the sheets in exactly the same size, which is the native image size. Checked using `apache poi 3.17` as wel as `apache poi 4.1.2`.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks for testing. What is your java version? I'm using:
java version "1.8.0_271" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode) 
Mac OS

Comment: "Mac OS": Then it seems to be a problem of the used spreadsheet application. `Apache poi` code produces a correct result for `MIcrosoft Excel`. Not warranted for other spreadsheet applications.